# Error The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am writing a web api to get all my user from Database but it give this error
`The 'ObjectContent 1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'.`  I have Already added webapiconfig.cs file and all prerequisite for web api.

### WebApi

```
using Atea.Azure.ApiManagement.Entities;
using Atea.Azure.ApiMangement.Business;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Azure_API_Delegation_Portal.Controllers
{
    public class ApisController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public ApisController(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;

        }

        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            return _userService.AllUser();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
public JsonResult GetAllUsers()

{
   return Json(_userService.AllUser(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

}
```